# unable to output to the browser whilst PHP script is running with output buffering

Tags: php, apache, output, output-buffering

I have this PHP script below that, for some reason, doesn't allow me to output to the browser as the script is running. This is a heavy script and will likely run for 10-15 minutes in a production environment, so I would need to be able to see the output as it is progressing rather than just a massive output right at the end.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");

apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);

ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_start();

echo "Script STARTED at " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) . "<br />";

// get all the "payments"
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payments");
while ($payment = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // do a SQL update in here
    echo "Write out progress here...<br />";
}

echo "Script ENDED at " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) . "<br />";
```

An `httpd -v` gives me:

> Server version: Apache/2.2.3  Server built:   Oct 20 2011 17:00:12

and I am running PHP 5.3.27

I've taken some code in this script from other SO posts, but this current setup does not work.

Comment: U need to flush after your `echo`'s. There is an option where every `echo`will flush automatically tho (can't remember it atm)

Comment: @DarkBee Is that an `ob_flush` or just a `flush`? Does it have to go after every `echo` (I have more than one in this script)?

Comment: Both, u can do it after a serveral amount of `echo`'s if u want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to flush after each echo with

```
flush(); ob_flush();
```

Although it might not work because of server setting

```
 flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has      no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser. [...]

 Several servers, especially on Win32, will still buffer the output from your script until it terminates before transmitting the results to the browser.

 Server modules for Apache like mod_gzip may do buffering of their own that will cause flush() to not result in data being sent immediately to the client.
```

[from stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324963/how-to-correctly-show-output-at-every-echo-on-all-browsers?rq=1)
[flush documentation](http://php.net/flush)

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me, I should add I also had to uncomment this in php.ini `output_buffering Default Value: Off` More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324963/how-to-correctly-show-output-at-every-echo-on-all-browsers?rq=1